# How to Change Sidebar Font Color?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[somebody plis help me with this. **I didn't change anything in my vs code but why is the sidebar font color like this?** i want it back to default, i try everything but it doesnt work. Please help me:)
[here the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq2N2.png)

i try to change it with
"

> workbench.colorCustomizations": {
> "sideBar.background" : "#1A1A1A"}

but it just change the background color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's **Github Source Control**

You probably initalized a git repository in the folder you were working on. Just locate the hidden **.git** folder in the root of your folder and delete it. That will remove the source control

Comment: oh my god, thanks man. thank u so much:*